# How to set up all countries on this Active directory string?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have this string on a config file that allows a company employees login into the system:
ldap.dn=CN=%s,OU=Users,OU=XXX,OU=**CL**,DC=xxx-dc,DC=xxx,DC=com

For this string, only employees from Chile can access the application.

How can I set up this string to be open for any employee in the world?

If it's not possible, how can I set it for 2 or more countries?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If it's on-prem only you can deploy a [central access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/solution-guides/deploy-a-central-access-policy--demonstration-steps-) that allows users to access from all or multiple countries.

If it's hybrid and you have Azure AD set up (you've tagged with Azure so it looks like you might), you can set up Named Locations and allow access from those countries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location

Comment: You can also set up separate OUs within each location so that people can access all or some. https://theitbros.com/active-directory-organizational-unit-ou/